# Filter, then map? Or just use a for loop?

Tags: clojure

I keep running into situations where I need to filter a collection of maps by some function, and then pull out one value from each of the resulting maps to make my final collection.

I often use this basic structure:

```
(map :key (filter some-predicate coll))
```

It occurred to me that this basically accomplishes the same thing as a for loop:

```
(for [x coll :when (some-predicate x)] (:key x))
```

Is one way more efficient than the other? I would think the `for` version would be more efficient since we only go through the collection once.. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither is significantly different.

Both of these return an unrealized lazy sequence where each time an item is read it is computed. The first one does not traverse the list twice, it instead creates one lazy sequence which that produces items that match the filter and is then immediately consumed (still lazily) by the map function. So in this first case you have one lazy sequence consuming items from another lazy sequence lazily. The call to `for` on the other hand produces a single lazy-seq with a lot of logic in each step.

You can see the code that the for example expands into with:

```
(pprint (macroexpand-1 '(for [x coll :when (some-predicate x)] (:key x))))
```

On the whole the performance will be very similar with the second method perhaps producing slightly less garbage so the only way for you to decide between these on the basis of performance will be benchmarking. On the basis of style, I choose the first one because it is shorter, though I might choose to write it with the thread-last macro if there where more stages.

```
(->> coll
     (filter some-predicate)
     (take some-limit)
     (map :key))
```

Though this basically comes down to personal style

Comment: That `macroexpand-1` was enlightening. Thank you for the great answer